# Make $(window).scroll(), scroll a specific element

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have a document, with all elements position:fixed, and html and body has overflow:hidden.

At the center of the page, I have an element with a specified height also with overflow:hidden. However, the content of this element does have an overflow, but I need to hide the nasty scrollbar.
This container has an inner-wrapper, which of course allows me to get the actual height of the content.

I have tried tried making an overlay element with full window size, with an inner element with the same height as my inner-content wrapper, but I can't seem to make work as intended.

Is there anyways to achieve what I'm trying to to? ... Hide all scrollbar but still allow mousewheel to scroll the content of that specific element, regardsless of where the cursor is placed?

An example of what I'm thinking:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="jquerylib-bla-bla.js" />
    <style>
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #element {
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            margin: -250px 0 0 -250px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(window).mousewheel(function() {
                $('#element').trigger('scroll'); // However, this is not possible :)
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="element">
        <div id="element-inner">
            Some content that exceeds the height #element.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: If i understand your question, you want to hide the scroller on the window and show it on mouseover?

Comment: Lowkase: Don't give me that common comment. I could give you my HTML, but it should be obvious based on my description :)

Comment: HaBo: No not exactly. Actually, I don't want any scrollbars to ever show, but I want to let the 'mousewheel' event trigger a scroll event in my #content. Just for fun I tried $('window').scroll(function() { $('#content').trigger('scroll'); }); but I guess it was not that simple :D

Comment: It might be obvious, but why force us to re-create it just so that we can experiment with your problem?